# SSRS: Issues with blank Columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

```
select 
    IntervalDate, 
    TeamName, 
    tsystem.name as SystemName
from vwCount
inner join tsystem
    on vwCount.systemID = tsystem.id 
where IntervalDate >= @StartDateTime
    AND IntervalDate <= @EndDateTime 
    AND tsystem.ID in (select SystemID
                       from tSystemViewSystem
                       where SystemViewID = 4
                      )
    AND Teamname != ''
```

In my Tablix there are rows which should not display.

[image]

And therefore I set in the where clause

```
AND Teamname != ''
```

If I use this function then the report do not display the rows with a blank Team row. But here is a problem. I would like to show the `21.01.2017` but there is nothing in the Team column and if I use the function above then the 21.01.2017 do not display. how can I display `21.01.2017` in the tablix even though the Team column is blank?

Comment: Why do you want to show the 21st but not the 22nd?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `or`:

```
where IntervalDate >= @StartDateTime AND IntervalDate <= @EndDateTime and
      tsystem.ID in (Select SystemID
                     from tSystemViewSystem
                     where SystemViewID = 4
                    ) and   
      (Teamname <> '' or datum = '2017-01-21')
```

(This assumes that `datum` is a `date`, so you can use ISO standard formats for the constants.)